# Detecting complete end of motion in MapBox Android

Tags: android, mapbox

I'm looking to detect complete end of motion of the map in the Android SDK of MapBox. By complete end I mean no more user interaction (touch) and camera movement (touch move or fling inertia).

As there is no such callback in the SDK, I combined two listeners on the `MapView`, `OnTouchListener` and `OnMapChangedListener` like so (in Kotlin but pretty clear):

```
mapView.setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
    when (event.actionMasked) {
        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
            listener?.onMapDragBegin()
        }
        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
            listener?.onMapDragEnd()
        }
    }
    false
}

mapView.addOnMapChangedListener { c ->
    when (c) {
        MapView.REGION_WILL_CHANGE, MapView.REGION_WILL_CHANGE_ANIMATED -> {
            listener?.onMapMovementBegin()
        }
        MapView.REGION_DID_CHANGE, MapView.REGION_DID_CHANGE_ANIMATED -> {
            listener?.onMapMovementEnd()
        }
    }
}
```

The listener waits for both events to have ended. This works pretty well, except for one tiny detail: when flinging, both end events are sent when the user stops touching the screen, and only after is the `REGION_WILL_CHANGE_ANIMATED` map change invoked. So there's a moment at which I can't know whether the map is still moving or not. Looks like this in the logs:

```
19:23:42.431: Map touch started
19:23:42.537: Map region change started
19:23:42.538: Map region change ended
...
19:23:42.570: Map region change started
19:23:42.570: Map region change ended
19:23:42.577: Map touch ended
19:23:42.577: Map movement ended at -122,420511, 37,748315
// Both touch and movement now have ended according to the MapView
// Fling inertia begins
19:23:42.582: Map region change started
19:23:43.154: Map region change ended
19:23:43.154: Map movement ended at -122,424123, 37,741793
```

I need to do an API call after the movement ended. If the map starts moving again I will cancel any active call so it's not a huge issue, but I'd like to know if the SDK provides a way to avoid having this call/cancel/call every time the user flings the map. For example I've thought of checking any scroll speed at the end of the movement but coulnd't find any way to access it.

Comment: The SDK exposes an `OnFlingListener` that is called for each fling invocation. Related to MapChange events there are other events as `DID_FINISH_RENDERING_FRAME_FULLY_RENDERED`

Comment: @Tobrun I forgot to mention but I already looked into `OnFlingListener` and it's not helpful at all, it's only called after the `REGION_WILL_CHANGE_ANIMATED` (region change from the fling inertia). I just tried `DID_FINISH_RENDERING_FRAME_FULLY_RENDERED` and it's unusable too (I believe it's for individual tiles). Other events such as `RENDERING_MAP_FULLY...` also are sent multiple times during a fling unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

There is a method [OnCameraIdleListener](https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/api/map-sdk/5.1.0/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/maps/MapboxMap.OnCameraIdleListener.html), which seems to appear in a recent version of the SDK. It is called when camera movement has ended.

Comment: It was added with the v5.1.0 I believe, but the issue is that it is called two times during a fling, first when the touch ends and the inertia begins, and then when the inertia ends. So a timer is still needed to filter out the first one.

Comment: It's strange that it called twice. I'm wondering, why it is implemented this way, because it seems more logical, if the method is not called when the touch ends, but the camera is still moving.

Comment: @matinashtiani You should ask a new question or report an issue, if you think that there is an error in Mapbox SDK

Answer (score 0):

My solution use this listener in order to capture users gesture:

```
 map.addOnMoveListener(object : MapboxMap.OnMoveListener {
        override fun onMoveBegin(detector: MoveGestureDetector) {
            // user started moving the map
        }

        override fun onMove(detector: MoveGestureDetector) {
            // user is moving the map
        }

        override fun onMoveEnd(detector: MoveGestureDetector) {
            // user stopped moving the map
            Timber.d("Load assets {START}")

            val fence = mapManager.getFenceFromMap()
            val zoom = map.cameraPosition.zoom
            presenter.getMapAssets(fence,zoom)

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late, but if someone's looking for the same thing, this worked for me:

```
private val mapMoveListener = object : MapboxMap.OnMoveListener {
    //last point coordinates
    var lastX = 0F
    var lastY = 0F
    override fun onMoveBegin(detector: MoveGestureDetector) {
        //remember start coordinates of user's finger
        lastX = detector.focalPoint.x
        lastY = detector.focalPoint.y
    }
    override fun onMoveEnd(detector: MoveGestureDetector) {
        val deltaX = detector.focalPoint.x - lastX
        val deltaY = detector.focalPoint.y - lastY
        if (abs(deltaX) > MIN_MOVE_DELTA || abs(deltaY) > MIN_MOVE_DELTA) {
            this@MapEventsFragment.mapboxMap?.addOnCameraIdleListener(object : MapboxMap.OnCameraIdleListener {
                override fun onCameraIdle() {
                    getNearbyEvents()
                    this@MapEventsFragment.mapboxMap?.removeOnCameraIdleListener(this)
                }
            })
        }
    }
    override fun onMove(detector: MoveGestureDetector) {
    }
}
```